# Plot a bar chart from an aggregated pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I need help creating a bar chart from an aggregated data frame similar to the one shown in the picture. I want to plot in the x-axis the column "clase_size_poly" and compare in a bar chart the "<lambda_0>" value for all indices (NBR, NDFI_GV,...).

the dataframe has been created as:

```
grouped_df_identif = df_identif.groupby(['index', 'clase_size_poly']).agg({'identif_01': ['sum','count', lambda x: x.sum() / x.count()*100]})
```

The dataframe look like:

[image]

I tried the following code but got the error:
KeyError: '<lambda_0>':

```
#Plot a bar chart comparing the '<lambda_0>' column for each 'index' within each 'clase_size_poly'
df.plot(kind='bar', y='<lambda_0>', col='index')
#Show the plot
plt.show()
```

Comment: run following code `df.get('<lambda_0>', 'dont exist')`  then, what does it return?

Comment: The first thing I'm suspicious of is that your code suddenly applied plot to `df` without considering `grouped_df_identiff`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us select the desired column then reshape into wide format

```
grouped_df_identif[('identif_01', '<lambda_0>')].unstack(0).plot(kind='bar')
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have a MultiIndex on the columns, so you need to index it correctly:

```
grouped_df_identif['identif_01'].plot(kind='bar', y='<lambda_0>')
```

Or:

```
grouped_df_identif.plot(kind='bar', y=('identif_01', '<lambda_0>'))
```

*NB. "col" is not a valid keyword for [`plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html).*